# selenium error when checking for attribute in try loop

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

```
url='https://relatedwords.org/relatedto/music'
headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626'}
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/home/timmy/Python/chromedriver",chrome_options=options)
driver.get(url)
MAXIMUM_NUMBER=8
MINIMUM_NUMBER=0
ListWords=[]
for i in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@id=""]'):
    try:
        i=i.get_attribute("href").split("/")[-1]
        if "%20"in i:
            i=i.replace("%20"," ")
        ListWords.append(i)
        print("New Word added to our database:  %s"%i
    except:
        pass

    MINIMUM_NUMBER+=1
    if MINIMUM_NUMBER==MAXIMUM_NUMBER:
        break

print(ListWords)
```

when i run this code i get the following error

```
  File "/home/timmy/Python/1.py", line 18
    except:
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am not sure why its syntax error i tried

`except Exception as e:
    pass` but it didn't work 
The purpose of the program is to get the top 8 related words from the site in code and store them in `ListWords`
can someone tell me what am i doing wrong,and how to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to close brackets . Change it

```
 print("New Word added to our database:  %s"%i)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have missed a `)` in line `print("New Word added to our database:  %s"%i`

Comment: yes i figured, i almost pulled all my hair out thank you sir